# How do I post an issue ticket to the GitHub OSGEO/Ggdal repository?

Tags: gdal, github

After finding an issue with the gdal.py script, I would like to report the issue to Gdal. I looked to the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal) and did not see where to post the issue.

[The issue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/257109/gdaldem-alpha-flag-in-python-bindings-is-missing/257118#257118)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GDAL uses the OSGEO bug tracker - https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal

Comment: The bug tracker is there but please do not create a ticket right away. Write a mail to gdal-devel mailing list https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/gdal-dev first and tell about your problem. Well, your issue is quite well described and analyzed and probably qualifies as an issue report but it does not pay much to ask first.